# Render from pixel buffer to canvas, or render multiple DOM elements to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Say I have a canvas with multiple layers and multiple

elements on top of it and I want to render all of that to another canvas on a different part of the page.  Can this be done?

is it possible to just render whatever is on some part of the screen at a pixel level to a canvas?

Comment: This behavior is typically simulated by effectively re-rendering the DOM in a canvas element, not actually copying pixels directly. See this related question and a sample implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

Comment: It would be a bit scary if any website could see anything on any of your screens, render it to a canvas, maybe go ahead and send it somewhere? Or maybe I misunderstood your question and what you mean by "part of the screen"